# HTML Agility Pack or HTML Screen Scraping libraries for Java, Ruby, Python?

Tags: java, python, html, ruby, screen-scraping

I found the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) useful and easy to use for screen scraping web sites.  What's the equivalent library for HTML screen scraping in Java, Ruby, Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found what I was looking for:
[Options for HTML scraping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping)

Comment: The link is broken, could you please share what did you find years ago?

Answer (score 3):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is the standard Python screen scraping tool.

Recently, however, I used the (incomplete at the moment) [pyQuery](http://pyquery.org/), which is more or less a rewrite of jQuery into python, and found it to be very useful.

Comment: I would also suggest Scrapy for a robust infrastructure.